# Using Properties with Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have few properties in my Properties file like

```
dataCenterOptions.host="xyz"
dataCenterOptions.user="abc"
dataCenterOptions.password="def"
dataCenterOptions.port="ghi"
```

I'm using this is in my Spring class by annotating it with `@Value`. However instead of creating four separate variables can I have a single variable to access each of the following variables. Something like

```
@Value("${dataCenterOptions}")
Properties dataCenterProps;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Oneway is

At code

```
@Resource(name="prop")
Properties prop;
```

At config file

```
<util:properties id="prop" location="properties/dataCenterOptions.properties" />
```

Comment: but that will get all properties in that properties variable. I just need those that begin with "dataCenterOptions.*"